# JButton keyboard shortcuts

Tags: java, swing, keyboard, jbutton, shortcut

I have two `JButton`s and I would like to allow them to be used by the keyboard arrow keys whenever the `JFrame` has the focus.

Can anyone point me in the right direction about this?

Answer (score 3):

Modified from Swing's [Action](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) demo.

The initialization of your button:

```
// Sets the mnemonic to down, with no hint display
JButton down = new JButton(new DownAction("Down", null, "This is the down button", new Integer(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN));
```

The action:

```
class DownAction extends AbstractAction {
    public DownAction(String text, ImageIcon icon,
                  String desc, Integer mnemonic) {
        super(text, icon);
        putValue(SHORT_DESCRIPTION, desc);
        putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        displayResult("Action for first button/menu item", e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To intercept the keys (without worrying if the specific component is in focus) you should use the `InputMap`. Read up on for instance:

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html

And go for the `WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW` constant.

Unless the button in question simply calls a single method, the best way to do "what ever the button does" is to do:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        ((AbstractButton) c).doClick();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, when you say you want to allow them to use the "arrow keys", I assume you mean you want to be able to transfer focus. If this is the case then read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use the Focus Subsystem](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html). It gives an example of how you can use the Enter key for this.